# hibernate mappin could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table

Tags: hibernate

When running my application I ran into following error

> could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: Users, for
>   columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(roles)]

This is my current code and I can't figure out why I receive this error

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
public class UserEntity extends BaseEntity  {


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8789920463809744548L;

private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String username;
private String password;
private String role;


@OneToMany(mappedBy="mouad",targetEntity=Role.class)
private List<Role> roles;


public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}
public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}
public String getRole() {
    return role;
}
public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}
public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {

     //PasswordEncoder crypto = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
   // this.password = crypto.encodePassword(password, null);
  //  System.out.println(this.password);
    this.password=password;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Role")
public class Role extends BaseEntity  {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



private String rolename;
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = UserEntity.class)
private UserEntity mouad;

public UserEntity getMouad() {
    return mouad;
}

public void setMouad(UserEntity mouad) {
    this.mouad = mouad;
}

public String getRolename() {
    return rolename;
}

public void setRolename(String rolename) {
    this.rolename = rolename;
}
}
```

What could cause this error to happen? Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: You really should check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Quality questions receive quality answers :)

Comment: The given exception is only shown for simple values. It seems that your are either using `AccessType.PROPERTY` or that your `List` is no `java.util.List`. Can you check both?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the targetEntity on both the @ManyToOne and the @OneToMany

Try instead for the parent

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="mouad")
```

And for the child

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "<FOREIGN_KEY>")
```

Comment: it not solving the problem can you give me another solution

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: antlr.collections.List, at table: Users, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(roler)]
 at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:316)
 at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:294)
 at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:239)
 at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:469)
 at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1294)